CNN - LSTM Model (Time Sequential Video Frame Data)
During training, I use videos consisting of 16,000 frames, processing them in batches of 200 frames each for the model. For each dataset, I achieve values close to the actual data at the end of training. However, when I start training with a different dataset, the initial predictions tend to be very close to the last predicted values of the previous dataset. In other words, instead of starting with an estimate based on the new dataset, it seems to predict values close to the last obtained results, seemingly independent of the input. I'm not sure if this indicates overfitting or if there's another problem with my model. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?
Here is my model:
class FrequencyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FrequencyModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 8, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.pool = nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d((16, 16))
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(8)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.batchnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 16 * 16, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 128)

        #self.lstm_cell = CustomLSTMCell(128, 32)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=128 hidden_size=10, batch_first=True)  # Built-in LSTM layer

        self.fc_freq = nn.Linear(32, 3)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()


    def forward(self, frames):
        batch_size, timesteps, channels, H, W = frames.shape

        x = frames.view(-1, channels, H, W)
        x = self.pool(self.relu(self.batchnorm1(self.conv1(x))))
        x = self.pool(self.relu(self.batchnorm2(self.conv2(x))))
        x = self.pool(self.relu(self.batchnorm3(self.conv3(x))))
        x = x.view(batch_size, timesteps, -1)

        combined_features = x
        combined_features = combined_features.view(batch_size * timesteps, -1)
        combined_features = self.relu(self.fc1(combined_features))
        combined_features = self.relu(self.fc2(combined_features))
        combined_features = combined_features.view(batch_size, timesteps, -1)

        h_0 = torch.zeros(1, batch_size, 10).to(frames.device)  # (num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)
        c_0 = torch.zeros(1, batch_size, 10).to(frames.device)  # (num_layers, batch_size, hidden_size)

        lstm_out, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm(combined_features, (h_0, c_0))  # LSTM forward pass
        output = self.fc_freq(lstm_out[:, -1, :])  # Use the output of the last time step

        #output = self.fc_freq(h_t)
        return output

I want to predict three different value from the video frames. However, after each dataset, the predicted values are almost similar to previous actual value.

When you say the initial predictions tend to be very close to the last predicted values of the previous dataset are you talking about the dataset broadly or the specific last batch? If values are close to the specific last input, there's a bug somewhere. However, if the outputs are simply around the mean/var of the previous dataset, that is expected. Your model learns the distribution of the dataset and assumes all inference data is drawn from the same distribution.

Let me make the situation more understandable. I created a dataset with video frames consisting of 16000 frames and completed the first dataset training using all of these frames. When I start training again with a completely different dataset, the values ​​predicted by the model are very close to the actual value of the previous dataset. The model learns the previous dataset well, but when I give a new input, I think it needs to find a different value according to the weights values.
